# sp_send_dbmail @from_address - add multiple emails?

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm trying to receive bounce back emails to multiple accounts, and I have tried setting up a email box that forwards out, but that isn't working. Is there a way to add multiple email addresses into the @from_address parameter?

```
    EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                @profile_name       = @profile_name,
                @recipients         = 'test@test.com',
                @subject            = 'test',
                @body               = 'works',
                @body_format        = 'HTML',
                @from_address       = @email
```

The above code works with an email being bounced back, but is there a way to add multiple emails to the @from_address. CCing doesn't work as it just sends them the email and doesn't include the bounce back

@from_address       = 'email1; email2' - doesn't work

Comment: An email can't have more than one sender, that's not a limitation of SQL Server. It *is* legal to have more than one reply address (`Reply-To`) but that's not supported by DBMail (and even if it was, bounce messages may not be directed there). You'll need to solve this on the email server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An email can only be from a single address, however your `@recipients` should be able to contain multiple email addresses:

```
@recipients = 'test@test.com; test2@test.com'
...
@from_address = 'from@test.com'
```

If you want to have multiple people see a bounce-back email, configure an email, i.e. `errors@test.com` and allow multiple people to access that email.